# F# Cutting a list in half using functional programming

Tags: recursion, f#, functional-programming

I am trying to input a list into the function and it send me a list with the first half of the elements taken away using f# with the below recursion but I keep running into a base case problem that I just cant figure out.  any thoughts?  I am using the second shadow list to count how far I need to go until I am half way into the list (by removing two elements at a time)

```
let rec dropHalf listToDrop shadowList = 
    match shadowList with
    | [] -> listToDrop
    | shadowHead2::shadowHead1::shadowTail -> if shadowTail.Length<=1 then listToDrop else 
                                    match listToDrop with 
                                    |[] -> listToDrop
                                    |listToDropHead::listToDropTail -> dropHalf listToDropTail shadowTail
```

Comment: is there a specific reason for your chosen implementation? There are easier, simpler ways to get half of a given list.

Comment: well this is a small function on a bigger peiece of an assignment and the whole thing is centered around doing this in a functional programming way (we all come from c++ backgrounds).  So I assumed recursion.

Comment: does it matter to you which elements in the list are kept and which are discarded.

Comment: if you can use library functions, just find the length and drop half of it.  if you can't, you might still find implementing that simplest.  obviously when doing exercises you sometimes have to do "odd" things to learn, but in practice what i described is probably the way most people would do it...  HOWEVER i do worry that perhaps you are getting some "higher level" part of your exercise wrong.  this seems an odd thing to do - throwing away half your data.

Comment: Im not its for an assignment.  I know it is odd but I'm trying to make it this way or some other way that works with recurssion.  She hinted and the shadow copy way of doing this in class in fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let rec dropHalf listToDrop shadowList = 
    match shadowList with
    | [] -> listToDrop
    | shadowHead2::[] -> listToDrop   (* odd number! *)
    | shadowHead1::shadowHead2::shadowTail -> 
        match listToDrop with 
        | [] -> listToDrop   (* should never happen? *)
        | listToDropHead::listToDropTail -> dropHalf listToDropTail shadowTail
```

i'm afraid i don't use F#, but it's similar to ocaml, so hopefully the following is close to what you're looking for (maybe the comment format has changed?!).  the idea is that when you exhaust the shadow you're done.  your code was almost there, but the test for length on the shadow tail made no sense.

i want to emphasize that this isn't anything like anyone would write "in real life", but it sounds like you're battling with some weird requirements.

Comment: Thanks.  Its the late hour and I am no longer thinking clearly.  This was very close to what I was looking for!

Comment: good luck.  learning fp has improved my code in languages like c + java no end.  it takes a long time to really click, but it's worth it, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use the shadow list with the same length as the original list and remove elements from these lists with different rates, it's better to create an auxiliary function:

```
let dropHalf xs =
    let rec dropHalf' ys zs =
      match ys, zs with
      | _::_::ys', _::zs' -> dropHalf' ys' zs'
      | _, zs' -> zs' (* One half of the shadow list ys *)
    dropHalf' xs xs
```

If you don't care to traverse the list twice, the following solution is simpler:

```
let rec drop n xs =
   match xs, n with
   | _ when n < 0 -> failwith "n should be greater or equals to 0"
   | [], _ -> []
   | _, 0 -> xs
   | _::xs', _ -> drop (n-1) xs'

let dropHalf xs =
    xs |> drop (List.length xs/2)
```

and another simple solution needs some extra space but doesn't have to use recursion:

```
let dropHalf xs = 
    let xa = Array.ofList xs
    xa.[xa.Length/2..] |> List.ofArray
```

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, if you're calling `Length` on a list, then there is most likely a better way to do what you're doing.  `Length` has to iterate the entire list and is therefore O(n).

```
let secondHalf list =
    let rec half (result : 'a list) = function
        | a::b::sx -> half result.Tail sx
        // uncomment to remove odd value from second half
        // | (a::sx) -> result.Tail 
        | _ -> result

    half list list
```

Comment: Thanks!  Seems to be a lot of confusion on my question and I think this comes from the fact that everyone is trying to throw every construct into their programming languages now adays that the lines between different programming approaches are getting blurred.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample does what you described.

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic

let items = seq { 1 .. 100 } |> Seq.toList

let getBackOfList ( targetList : int list) = 
    if (targetList.Length = 0) then 
        targetList
    else
        let len = targetList.Length
        let halfLen = len / 2
        targetList |> Seq.skip halfLen |> Seq.toList

let shortList = items |> getBackOfList

("Len: {0}", shortList.Length) |> Console.WriteLine

let result = Console.ReadLine()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your using libraries like Length which isnt purely functional